# How to exit from Contiki code?

Tags: c, contiki

Please find below attached snapshot of my code output. Every time when I execute my code, I have to use ctrl+c (cmd+c) to exit. Is there any function in Contiki's library which will help me to resolve this issue?
Thank you in advance!!!

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HKDQ.png)

[How to exit from this program without manually entering ctrl+C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPnJ7.png)

Comment: which code? I don't see any code.

Comment: Can you click to "How to exit from this code?"

Comment: No code there too.

Comment: You [end the process](http://contiki.sourceforge.net/docs/2.6/a01671.html#ga9c2681a0070eba8a7c9fdf4dbb6db05e)?

Comment: What @EugeneSh. is asking for is the actual code. Or rather (and preferably) a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @EugeneSh. How to get exit from any contiki code? I have ended the process but still have to press "cmd+c"

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have ended the process. but still have to enter cmd+c to exit.

Comment: Read [ask] and follow the advice!

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have edited my question. You can see both now .. (My code + My doubt) Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you help now? Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contiki OS is for running programs on small devices autonomously. Such programs usually execute in an infinite loop awaiting for sensor inputs or scheduled timeouts, hence no need for exiting. You are probably asking about a special case, where you want to execute some code natively on a Linux PC, and then kill the program along with the whole Contiki OS, which in this case is a single Linux process. Therefore, pressing Ctrl+C is the correct way to do that.

Because your program is compiled and linked together with Contiki, you can put an exit() in your program to exit Contiki, if you really want to skip the Ctrl+C:

```
include <stdlib.h>
...
PROCESS_THREAD(hello_world_process, ev, data)
{
  PROCESS_BEGIN();

  printf("Hello, world\n");
  exit(0);

  PROCESS_END();
}
```

But this is only useful when you run the program natively; on an embedded device, you probably would want a system reset, rather than an exit that leaves the device "dead".

Comment: @SH' Glad to hear that it helped. Answer accepted, then?